# Error: Redis connection to 10.130.212.246:6379 failed - connect ETIMEDOUT

Tags: node.js, redis, sails.js

I have a sails app. I am running the app in AWS. When i run the code in development mode(sails lift --verbose) it works fine. I am able to access it from the browser bye typing the Ip and port no.(xx.xx.xxx.xx:1337/). But when i run the code in production mode (sails lift --prod --verbose) i am not able to access by ip(xx.xx.xxx.xx) when i try with xx.xx.xxx.xx:1337 it gives me the below error.

```
Grunt :: Done, without errors.    

Unable to parse HTTP body- error occurred:
Error: Redis connection to 10.130.212.246:6379 failed - connect ETIMEDOUT
   at RedisClient.flush_and_error  (/home/ubuntu/vka/node_modules/sails/node_modules/connect- redis/node_modules/redis/index.js:142:13)
    at RedisClient.on_error (/home/ubuntu/vka/node_modules/sails/node_modules/connect-redis/node_modules/redis/index.js:180:10)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/vka/node_modules/sails/node_modules/connect-redis/node_modules/redis/index.js:95:14)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at net.js:441:14
    at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:492:13) [Error: Redis connection to 10.130.212.246:6379 failed - connect ETIMEDOUT]
Unable to parse HTTP body- error occurred:
Error: Redis connection to 10.130.212.246:6379 failed - connect ETIMEDOUT
at RedisClient.flush_and_error (/home/ubuntu/vka/node_modules/sails/node_modules/connect-redis/node_modules/redis/index.js:142:13)
at RedisClient.on_error (/home/ubuntu/vka/node_modules/sails/node_modules/connect-redis/node_modules/redis/index.js:180:10)
at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/vka/node_modules/sails/node_modules/connect-redis/node_modules/redis/index.js:95:14)
at Socket.emit (events.js:95:17)
at net.js:441:14
at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:492:13) [Error: Redis connection to 10.130.212.246:6379 failed - connect ETIMEDOUT]
```

please suggest a possible solution.

Comment: which version of connect-redis module have you installed ? make sure you install version 1.4.5 by `npm install connect-redis@1.4.5 --save` Also make sure the redis server is running.

Comment: Tried it. not working.

Comment: Check if you are hardcoding the host in `session.js` with ip, change it to `localhost`

Comment: yes ip was hardcoded. i can access the with typing xx.xx.xxx.xx:1337

Comment: How to access it without using port no 1337 and with aws puclic ip directly??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if you are hardcoding the host in `session.js` with ip, change it to `localhost`.

For your question on how to access without port `1337`, You need to set up a reverse proxy, say NginX, open up just the port 80 for public access, configure nginx to route the request coming to port 80 to your sails app running on port 1337, use something like `pm2` or `forever` to run the sails app.

Steps to setup NginX as reverse proxy is explained here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: I have edited the server iptables to:

-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT

Open 443 port i.e. HTTPS

-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEP

Comment: using NginX has its advantages, you can run multiple instances of a node application in same machine and configure nginx to route requests to each applications, a kind of load balancer for simple applications. Manage SSL connections etc..